# Google YouTube Data v3 API Blocked From Uploading Videos

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Recently I have been using **multiple** scripts that allow you to upload a video via the YouTube Data v3 API from GCP.

However, the videos always gets auto privated and locked. I have done research and found out it's because you need verification on your API key or whatever.

Does anyone know how to get the API key verified or to be able to use the API to upload videos without it being auto locked to private?

Answer (score 2):

> Does anyone know how to get the API key verified or to be able to use the API to upload videos without it being auto locked to private?

To be clear api keys are used to access private user data. To upload videos to YouTube you need to use Oauth2 and be authorized to access a users YouTube account

> However, the videos always gets auto privated and locked.

If you check the documentation for [Videos: insert](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert)  you will find the source of your issue and what you need to do to fix it.

> All videos uploaded via the videos.insert endpoint from unverified API projects created after 28 July 2020 will be restricted to private viewing mode. To lift this restriction, each API project must undergo an [audit](https://support.google.com/youtube/contact/yt_api_form) to verify compliance with the [Terms of Service](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert). Please see the API Revision History for more details.

Go though the verification process and then you will be able to upload public videos.

- [Unverified apps](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/7454865?hl=en)
- [What you need to know about Google verification](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lzIuNmNX9N8&t=5s)